# What is the purpose of beholder blood?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons

Beholders are large aberrations which supply their body with nutrients and oxygen by means of a network of tubes somewhere between a tracheal system and a set of digestive tubules. They also have blood which is pumped in and out of their heart, despite the fact that they already have a system to transport nutrients/oxygen. Why is this? Does this extra fluid have a purpose in the beholder's body?

Comment: *Unlike a humanoid heart that pumps blood around the body constantly, beholders had a central 'blood sac' that, in conjunction with a powerfully muscled diaphragm, pushed blood into the beholder's blood vessels, then pulled the blood back into the sac.* - https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/story-lore/158582-why-do-beholders-have-blood

Comment: Blood is life. It keeps you going. Makes you warm. Makes you hard. Makes you other than dead. Course it's got blood.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The main purpose of blood is to transport things required for life, which the beholder seems to have covered already

Comment: Perhaps the tubules carry different things to the blood? After all, humans have a circulatory system and a lymphatic system.

Comment: @Valorum - that is from a fiction novel, not entirely canon.

Comment: Where did you find the mention of blood, other than I, Tyrant? I find no mention of it in any of the editions Monster Manuals, nor is it in the Ecology article from Dragon #76? (And a search for beholder blood on the RPG site gets zero hits).

Comment: Isn't it the case that beholders are created by another Beholder dreaming of a Beholder? In that case it doesnt need a real function at all, the Beholder dreaming just have to assume it has a function to make it real.

Comment: @AdmiralAckbar - No, they lay eggs.